# Onenote 2013 - Automatically Copy Pages

Tags: ms-office, onenote

I want to create a onenote book which I then share with a load of students. Using a cool little tool MS have produced, it will create sections for each student which they can access so they can READ my bits and EDIT their own but NOT see each others - I can read and edit all. Fab.

But their pages are blank. I want to be able to hit a button/macro/script/whatever to copy a select page from my section in to each of the other sections. Without using VS preferably.

Any ideas?

Comment: i have a solutions which requires writing little code. is it OK?

Comment: Sorry - just seen this! I'd be happy to see a solution

Answer (score 0):

This tool that OneNote just released should make it doable, if you use the Win32 version of OneNote:
https://blogs.office.com/2016/03/08/introducing-the-class-notebook-add-in-for-onenote-designed-and-built-with-teachers/

Comment: I've been using that for quite a while (at least I was until I found our school couldn't actually get onenote working properly!). It doesn't do what I wanted, and MS couldn't figure out why I wanted them to.